# Different positonining of text element of createjs in different browsers

Tags: javascript, easeljs, createjs

The is slight difference in the **top position** of text object rendered by firefox to other browsers in CreateJs while the shapes object does not show this difference.

For instance,

```
this.text = new cjs.Text("Click to Start", '500 47px Hel');
this.text.textAlign = "center";
this.text.lineHeight = 110;
this.text.lineWidth = 289;
this.text.setTransform(119.5, 5);
```

it will give slightly different **top position** relative to the other graphics surrounding this text in firefox or chrome. Is there any way to solve this issue?

Comment: You might have implement a simple browser-sniffer, and make browser-specific changes.

Comment: I haven't tried anything browser specific. I have researched on the topic and found there is approx 7 px difference in the positioning of text in mozilla than in other browsers.The code i have is too long (above mentioned was a small fraction of that). So if i try detecting the browser and make changes in positioning that will be a time consuming process  so if anything else anyone can suggest that will be a great help.

Answer (score 0):

If your text is static (the button text never changes throughout the game / app) then you could decide to make the button an image.
A CreateJS canvas is an image anyway, so visually there should not be any difference.